# Redux React Modal Local Prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm super new to React and Redux, but how does one use local properties and redux properties at the same time? I've been trying different ways and none of them seem to work for my case, which is pretty simple and I'm sure there is a simple solution which in my inexperience I just can't see.

What I am trying to do: use redux to manage character state, but at the same time use local components to manage the modal(open and close it)
I'd like advice on how to use local states with this sort of code, or how I can change it to make isOpen property manageable on the local level.

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { Component, useState } from "react";

import { Character } from "../../../../Data/Character";
import StatusBar from "../../../Components/StatusBar";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";
import HealthCalculator from "./HealthCalculator";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { UpdateCurrentHealth } from "../../../../redux/actionCreators";

const mapStateToProps = (state: {
  currentHealth: any,
  maxHealth: any,
  classes: any[],
}) => {
  return {
    currentHealth: state.currentHealth,
    maxHealth: state.maxHealth,
    classes: state.classes,
    isOpen: false,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  updateCurrentHealth: (payload) => dispatch(UpdateCurrentHealth(payload)),
  toggleModal: () => ({}),
});

/....../

const HealthCard = (props: {
  currentHealth: number,
  maxHealth: number,
  classes: any[],
  isOpen: any,
}) => (
  <>
    <div className="card" style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
      <span style={{ fontSize: "20px", color: "#708F93" }}>Hit Points</span>
      <div className="HealthBar">
        <StatusBar
          bColor="#9DBE9E"
          fColor="#BAE6BC"
          value={(props.currentHealth / props.maxHealth) * 100}
          label={GetLabelHealth(props.currentHealth, props.maxHealth)}
        />
      </div>
      {props.classes.length >= 0 &&
        props.classes.map((c) => (
          <div style={{ marginTop: "2px" }}>
            <div className="HitPointsBar">
              <StatusBar
                bColor="#c5d2db"
                fColor="#D8E2E9"
                value={(c.currentHDie / c.classLevel) * 100}
                label={GetLabelHitDice(c.currentHDie, c.hitDie)}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
    <Modal
      show={props.isOpen}
      size="sm"
      aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
      centered
    >
      <Modal.Body bsPrefix="modalContentCard">
        <HealthCalculator />
      </Modal.Body>
    </Modal>
  </>
);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HealthCard);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to a single card handling the state of a modal instead of passing it trough `props.isOpen` than you can make a click event or what ever you need the modal to open to. I will change your example so that when your HealthCard renders, the modal will open, just to show you how hooks work, and closing it on click:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { Component, useState } from "react";

import { Character } from "../../../../Data/Character";
import StatusBar from "../../../Components/StatusBar";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";
import HealthCalculator from "./HealthCalculator";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { UpdateCurrentHealth } from "../../../../redux/actionCreators";
import { useEffect } from "react";

const mapStateToProps = (state: {
  currentHealth: any,
  maxHealth: any,
  classes: any[],
}) => {
  return {
    currentHealth: state.currentHealth,
    maxHealth: state.maxHealth,
    classes: state.classes,
    isOpen: false,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  updateCurrentHealth: (payload) => dispatch(UpdateCurrentHealth(payload)),
  toggleModal: () => ({}),
});

const HealthCard = (props: {
  currentHealth: number,
  maxHealth: number,
  classes: any[],
  isOpen: any,
}) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsOpen(true);
  }, []);

  const onModalClose = () => {
    setIsOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div
        className="card"
        style={{ textAlign: "center" }}
        onClick={onModalClose}
      >
        <span style={{ fontSize: "20px", color: "#708F93" }}>Hit Points</span>
        <div className="HealthBar">
          <StatusBar
            bColor="#9DBE9E"
            fColor="#BAE6BC"
            value={(props.currentHealth / props.maxHealth) * 100}
            label={GetLabelHealth(props.currentHealth, props.maxHealth)}
          />
        </div>
        {props.classes.length >= 0 &&
          props.classes.map((c) => (
            <div style={{ marginTop: "2px" }}>
              <div className="HitPointsBar">
                <StatusBar
                  bColor="#c5d2db"
                  fColor="#D8E2E9"
                  value={(c.currentHDie / c.classLevel) * 100}
                  label={GetLabelHitDice(c.currentHDie, c.hitDie)}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
      </div>
      <Modal
        show={isOpen}
        size="sm"
        aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
        centered
      >
        <Modal.Body bsPrefix="modalContentCard">
          <HealthCalculator />
        </Modal.Body>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HealthCard);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This answered my question, I tried something similar before but not exactly like this.

Comment: I am glad that my answer helped!

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic involved in maintaining both `local` state which is done via stateful class components or `useState` hook, and `redux` state. Since in your case modal `isOpen` state is considered local, and other props originate from redux then:

```js
interface Props {
    // ownProps
    isOpen: Boolean,
    setIsOpen: Function,
    // mappedProps
    currentHealth: number,
    maxHealth: number,
    classes: Array<any>,
    setCurrentHealth: Function
}

const HealthCard = ({
    isOpen,
    setIsOpen,
    currentHealth,
    maxHealth,
    classes,
    setCurrentHealth
}: Props) => {
    // component code
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => ({
    currentHealth: state.currentHealth,
    maxHealth: state.maxHealth,
    classes: state.classes,
});

// you can get dispatch type from redux types
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch) => ({
    updateCurrentHealth: (payload: any) => dispatch(UpdateCurrentHealth(payload)),
});;

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HealthCard);
```

Then you would call the component and pass only props which are considered `ownProps`:

```
const Parent = () => {
    const [ isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen ] = useState(false);
    const toggleIsModalOpen = (event: SyntheticEvent): void => {
        setIsModalOpen(!isModalOpen);
    };
    
    // ...
    return (
        <>
            // ...
            <HealthCard isOpen={isModalOpen} toggleModal={toggleIsModalOpen}/>
        </>
    );
};
```

For more information on the topic I would suggest deeper dive into [redux docs](https://redux.js.org/), [react-redux docs](https://react-redux.js.org/) and additionally [redux toolkit docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/), which is simply amazing  and removes plenty of useless boilerplate while also providing you with baseline setup for useful redux-related utilities ([reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect), [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) and others)

As a piece of useful information for the future, the `mapStateToProps` can also acces those `ownProps` that are passed into component directly, the function takes second, optional argument:

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    // in your case, you could access the props "isOpen" and "toggleIsOpen" on this level
    // and manipulate redux state with them before injecting it into the component
};
```

Hope this wall of text helps.